# How do I position a Label in Kivy Python?

Tags: python, kivy, label, positioning

Alright, my question is **"How can I position a Label in Kivy?"** like I do know, that in Tkinter we have a **"Place"** attribute in Labels. But, I am a new Kivy learner so I can't figure it out the placement of a kivy label in a kivy window. Here's a simple program I built.

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
    
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text = "Hey there! I am a Label!  [Place Me!]")
    
MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official kivy documentation about widget positioning](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.pos), there's 2 ways to do it:

1. Using the `pos` argument to assign widget's position by pixels, similar to the `x` and `y` argument from `tkinter`:

```python
def build(self):
    return Label(text = "Hey there! I am a Label!  [Place Me!]",
                pos = (200, 300),
                )
```

2. Using the `pos_hint` argument to assign widget's position as a fraction between 0.0 and 1.0 of the height and width of the window/parent widget, similar to the `relx` and `rely` argument from `tkinter`:

```python
def build(self):
    return Label(text = "Hey there! I am a Label!  [Place Me!]",
                pos_hint = (0.5, 0.35),
                )
```

Keep in mind that though it's pretty similar to how it works in `tkinter`, the `kivy`'s widgets are positioned based from the `left` and the `bottom` side of the window, different from the `left` and `top` fashion of `tkinter`, for example `relx=0.5, rely=0.3` would be at the same place as `pos_hint=(0.5,0.7)`.